# Reinstall mysql keeping db intact

Tags: mysql

basically on my vps somehow mysql.sock vanished in tmp as well lib folder. I want to reinstall mysql but will db get lost?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL stores its database files in `/var/lib/mysql` it's a good idea to backup this folder. Removing the `mysql` package should not remove this folder.

Comment: Thanks space,will just taking backup of dolder will suffice or anything else? irony is mysql.sock is missing and not even mysqldump is working

Comment: Just backup the files. If your MySQL server is not running, you won't be able to use `mysqldump`.

Comment: yup zipped all files,what do next?

Comment: zip is not a good idea. Better do `cd /var/lib; tar czf mysql-db.tar.gz mysql`. Then you should tell which system you're using.